# How can I repeat the program at the end of each "case" statement in c?

Tags: c, function, do-while

I am learning C and I have this project where I have to use arrays and stuff.

At the end of each `case`, I need to ask the user if he wants to repeat the whole program, and that's where I'm struggling.

I have tried using functions and `do while` loops but that didn't work.

my code right now is:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
  int i, opcao, vetor1[10], vetor2[10], vetor3[10], d, e, f, con4;
  float soma = 0.0, soma2, media, media2;

  printf("Digite um valor de 1 a 5:\n1-Media de valores\n2- Reverter vetor\n3- "
         "Separar os pares dos impares\n4- Subtração e o seu quadrado\n5- "
         "Novos valores e media \n");

  scanf("%d", &opcao);

  switch (opcao) {
  case 1:

    printf("Introduza 10 numeros ente 1 e 100\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      do {
        printf("Insira o digito nº%d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &vetor1[i]);
        soma += vetor1[i];
      } while (vetor1[i] < 1 || vetor1[i] > 100);
    }

    media = soma / 10;
    printf("Media = %.2f", media);

    return 0;

    break;

  case 2:

    printf("sum code");

    break;

  case 3:

    printf("sum code");

    break;

  case 4:

    printf("sum code");

    break;

  case 5:

    printf("sum code");

    break;
```

my code trying to use a function:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void continuando() // função que pergunta se o usuário que continuar o programa.
{
  char continuar;

  printf("\n\nwanna continua?");
  printf("\nif yes (s) if no (n)");
  scanf("%c", &continuar);
  scanf("%c", &continuar);

  switch (continuar) {
  case 's': {
    system("CLS"); // usado para limpar o ecrã.
    break;
  }

  case 'n': {
    printf("\nfinished program.");
    exit(0); // a função exit(0) é usada para terminar o programa.
    break;
  }
  default: {
    printf("Option invalid.");
    break;
  }
  }
}

main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

  int i, opcao, vetor1[10], vetor2[10], vetor3[10], d, e, f, con4;
  int media4, media5, media6, media7, media8, media9, media10, media11, media12,
      media13;
  float soma = 0.0, soma2, media, media2;

  printf("insert 20 nums\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    do {
      printf("Insira o digito nº%d: ", i + 1);
      scanf("%d", &vetor1[i]);
      soma += vetor1[i];
    } while (vetor1[i] < 1 || vetor1[i] > 100);
  }

  printf("Digite um valor de 1 a 5:\n1-Media de valores\n2- Reverter vetor\n3- "
         "Separar os pares dos impares\n4- Subtração e o seu quadrado\n5- "
         "Novos valores e media \n");

  scanf("%d", &opcao);

  do {

    switch (opcao) // opcao = option in eng
    {
    case 1:

      media = soma / 10;
      printf("average = %.2f", media);

      continuando();

      return 0;

      break;

    case 2:

      printf("sum code");

      break;

    case 0:
      printf("program finished");
      return 0;

      break;

    default:
      printf("invalid value!\n");
    }

  } while (opcao = !0);
}
```

Comment: Re: *i have tried using funtions and do while cycles but i had no success* then show us those attempts so we can point out where your mistake it.

Comment: ok just a sec mate

Comment: there it is, hope its more clear now

Comment: "I'm struggling" and "I had no success" are not problem descriptions. What exactly happens? Why is that wrong? What should happen instead? Show example input, desired output, and current output; and quote any errors received in full.

Comment: A tip: please start using a formatter: [`clang-format`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Using_Clang_Format.html), it helps you with keeping your code clean and your mind clear.

Comment: @tomas asking for continuation of the whole program after the end of each case means, run the 'whole' program, then ask for continuation and then act accordingly. That was described in my answer below. And how do you think your 'continuando' function does help, especially if it is followed by a 'return 0'?

Comment: well i don't know @ErdalKüçük, as i said i´m still learning and i don´t have much experience :/

Comment: @tomas i edited my answer below, maybe it is a bit clearer now what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a simple if statement and let the loop run with a bool value. So if the user doesn't want to continue the loop you just set the boll value to false and the loop will not continue, If the user answers yes, the bool value just stays true.

edit:
do like so

first put the whole `switch` statement in a `while` loop and before that create a new `bool` variable `run` and set it to true. Also you need a new `char` variable named ans.

```
while(run) { ... case statements}
```

and then you ask this before every `break;` in the `case` statements.

```
printf("\nDo you want to repeat the program?(y/n)";
scanf("%c", &ans);
if(ans == 'y') { run = true; }
if(ans == 'n') { run = false; }
```

that should work!

Comment: how can i do that? do you have an example just to help me visualise the idea?

Comment: i edited my answer

Comment: nice, thank's, let me try it

Comment: thank you, it worked, but i had to add another scanf and now its working 100% :)

Answer (score 1):

"at the end of each case i need to ask the user if he wants to repeat the whole program"

So why not pack your 'program' into a loop?

```
int main()
{
    bool active = true;

    do {

        //ask for routine/subprogram/functionality [1..N]
        switch (input) {
            case 1: runRoutine1(); break;
            case 2: runRoutine2(); break;
            //... for all the other
        }

        //ask for continuation [y|n]
        switch (input) {
            case 'n': active = false; break;
        }

    } while (active);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** use 'break' instead of 'return 0'. The latter terminates your 'whole' program.

Comment: ok i will  try that

Comment: and how to i set it to repeat at the end of each case, for example, if i go through case 1 and it asks the user if he wants to repeat, if yes it comes back asking what option the user wants out of those 5 i have

Comment: what is your "runroutine" function?

Comment: These are your routines (functions) based on the options, namely 1: Media de valores, 2: Reverter vetor, 3: Separar os pares dos impares, 4: Subtração e o seu quadrado, 5: Novos valores e media